# New Record instance similar to Oracle forms in ADF

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf, oracleforms

I need to execute the new record instance like the oracle forms in adf, how can i do that?

Comment: This question is clear if you know Oracle Forms and Oracle ADF.  If you are not familiar with those two technologies, please refrain from submitting close votes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct, recommended equivalent.  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/b31974/appendix_formstriggers.htm#ADFFD1446.

In ADF, clicking on another row (which would fire a WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE trigger in Oracle Forms) does nothing by default in ADF, except reposition the cursor.  The middle tier (your bean, your iterator object, your view object, etc) are not notified of the event.

You could maybe write some JavaScript to detect what is, by default, a client-side-only event and throw a server event (using `AdfCustomEvent.queue` in your JavaScript handler and a `af:serverListener` tag in your page).  But when something is very hard in ADF, it is often because you're trying to do something outside the ADF design paradigm.

Perhaps you should post a question about what you are trying to accomplish and someone could recommend an ADF feature to help you achieve that in a way that fits well with the ADF model.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @Matthew McPeak